# How to the show/hide the correct elements with 2 checkboxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two checkboxes to filter through recipes (stored on a database) on a website. The allergy filter HIDES all the recipes with the allergy selected but the diet filter SHOWS only the recipes with the diet selected. (i.e. if the user checks the peanut allergy and gluten free it will hide recipes with those filters.) Both checkboxes work individually, but having both of them checked shows the wrong recipes. For example, what I want to happen is if the user checks off peanut allergy and the vegan diet, I want to show recipes that have no peanuts and are vegan. I basically need a way to keep track of what recipes are showing from one checkbox and filter through those for the other checkbox.

Below is the code I have:

```
    function filterFilesList() {
        var rows = $('.file-row');

        var checkedAllergies = $("#filterControlsAllergies :checkbox:checked");
      var checkedDiet = $("#filterControlsDiet :checkbox:checked");


        if(checkedAllergies.length && checkedDiet.length){
          console.log("both selected");
          rows.show(200);
          var type1 = []
          var arr = checkedAllergies.map(function(){
             type1.push("." + $(this).val())

          }).get();
          var type2 = []
          var arr = checkedDiet.map(function(){
             type2.push("." + $(this).val())

          }).get();

          //Filter through database and show/hide recipes depending on both checkboxes


        } else if(checkedAllergies.length){
            rows.show(200);
          var type1 = []
            var arr = checkedAllergies.map(function(){
                 type1.push("." + $(this).val())

            }).get();

          for (let i = 0; i < type1.length; i++){
            $(type1[i]).hide(200);
          }



        } else if(checkedDiet.length){
          rows.hide(200);
          var type2 = []
          var arr = checkedDiet.map(function(){
             type2.push("." + $(this).val())

          }).get();

          for (let i = 0; i < type2.length; i++){
            $(type2[i]).show(200);
          }



          } else {
            rows.show();
          }
  }
```

Comment: Since you didn't post a code example of how you are actually handling the loops for the database search, a simple solution that I can think of is do the SHOW function loop first that shows the recipes based on the diet selected. Then after that, run the loop for the HIDE function so it then hides the recipes based on the allergies. There are many solutions to this, but that is probably the easiest without rewriting your code and HTML etc..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have two different ways to solve this problem.

1. Check API, use existing or create new filter by allergies and diet.
2. Filter at client side. To do this you need:

- Get list of recipes that should be hidden by allergy.
- Get recipes by diet. Show diet recipes only if they are absent in allergy list.

Please check code below:

```js
if(checkedAllergies.length && checkedDiet.length){
  rows.hide(200);
  var type1 = []
     checkedAllergies.map(function(){
     type1.push("." + $(this).val())

  }).get();
  
  //let's create set of allergies recipes, that we need to exclude
  let allergiesSet = new Set();
  for(let i=0;i<type1.length;i++){
    allergiesSet.add(type1[i]);
  }
  
  var type2 = []
  var arr = checkedDiet.map(function(){
     type2.push("." + $(this).val());
  }).get();

  //Filter through database and show/hide recipes depending on both checkboxes

  for (let i = 0; i < type2.length; i++){
    if(!allergiesSet.has(type2[i])) {$(type2[i]).show(200);};
  }
}
```